# Android Cursor looks too thin in EditText view with android:gravity='right'

Tags: android, android-edittext

Dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

EditText style:

```
<style name="EditTextValue" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:inputType">numberDecimal|numberSigned</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Cursor set manually at the beginning (it looks normal as in the middle):

[image: Cursor is normal]

Cursor at default position (too thin):

[image: Cursor is too thin]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug that affects text input fields on Android 4.4, 5.0, 5.1 and 6, especially on RTL layouts ("right to left", like Arabic and Hebrew) where the cursor starts on the right.

Consider adding at least 2 dip `paddingStart` (for RTL) or `paddingRight` (for LTR) to the EditText, and try to add it in the layout directly, instead of in the style.